# Azure Maps expressions documentation

Tags: azure, azure-maps

Is there documentation available for all of the available operation expressions that you can use with azure maps? I've looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.expression?view=azure-iot-typescript-latest) and it only describes what an expression does, not all the operations you can use. I've found a few, like `get`, `match`, `step`, etc by [looking at examples](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net). I would prefer to have a documented list of all operations with their input/output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation for Expressions in Azure Maps can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/data-driven-style-expressions-web-sdk